# How to use Livepatch to keep my computer more secure between restarts?

Tags: updates, update-manager

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 version. My software updater showed me some updates and I installed that. After updating, instead of restart now, it shows like the picture below. What to do now? [I clicked ok and then opened software updater again. But it shows the same thing]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to restart now or it would say to do so.

Livepatch is a service that allows you to apply security patches to a running kernel, without having to reboot.

By using this service, you are better able to keep that server safe from vulnerabilities--without having to take that server offline for a reboot.

It is doing what it is supposed to do.

It is offering to have you use this service.

If you have not done so already you need a Ubuntu One account.

Here are some step by step instructions on how to do that. https://ubunlog.com/en/como-hacerse-una-cuenta-de-ubuntu-one/

Comment: How to set it up to run? I clicked on left bottom corner (Settings and Livepatch...), it takes me to update tab under Software and Updates. If I click on Livepatch tab there, it says to sign in.

Comment: Follow the instructions [here](https://ubuntu.com/security/livepatch). You need to obtain a Ubuntu One Account to proceed.

Comment: Many many thanks to you. It worked and I solved the issue!